# Add loading animation when user clicks next on my form

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to figure out how to create a loading animation when a page is loading. I have found some examples online and tried to include them into my code but im not seeing the loading animation work. below is an example of my page flow.

#### Page flow breakdown

1. user will arrive on /image.html this page will have a form where I will need to collect some data from the user.
2. when the user clicks next to go to the next page which is /package.html I would like to have a page loader while the /package.html page is loading.

Also here is the working example of the loader I am using [loader example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

Also, just to add for completeness I am using bootstrap with python flask. I did not add the python code as I am not sure it is relevant, but in case it is needed I can surely add it.

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}


{%block body%}

<style type="text/css">

  .loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

</style>


<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
</div>

<!-- adding page loader-->
<div class="loader">
  <form class="container" id="needs-validation" novalidate name="HwQueryForm" action="{{ url_for('packages') }}" method="POST">
    <div style="padding-left: 1.0em" class="row">

          <label  for="select" class="control-label">Image:</label><br>
        <select id="Image" class="form-control" name="image" style="width: 82%" >
            {% for item in cur_releases %}
                <option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <br> 
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom03">TFTP Directory Path:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="TFTP Path" name="tftp_dir" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid TFTP Path.
            </div>
            <br>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom04">TFTP Server IP:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="TFTP Server IP" name="tftp_server_ip" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid TFTP Server IP.
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.loader` styles you have are intended to be on a single element (a spinner), not your whole form.

If you want it to cover your entire form, add a container inside it, make your form `position: relative;` and the container inside `position: absolute;`. And, hide it at first, because you want the user to be able to fill your form before submitting it. Then, use JS to show it.

Here is how I would do it:

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('needs-validation');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', showLoader);

function showLoader(e){
  this.querySelector('.loader-container').style.display = 'block';
  // the line below is just for the demo, it stops the form from submitting
  // so that you can see it works. Don't use it
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#needs-validation {
  /* .loader-container will be positionned relative to this */
  position: relative;
}

.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(240,240,240,.7);
  /* hide it at first */
  display: none;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  /* Add the following to center it */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -38px; /* half its width (border included) */
  margin-top: -38px; /* half its height */
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
                                                                                             <style>/* unrelated styles */body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}h1{font-size:1.5em;}</style>
<form id="needs-validation">
    <p>First name: <input type="text"></p>
    <p>Last name: <input type="text"></p>
    <p>Age: <input type="text"></p>
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
    <!-- insert your loader container here, inside the <form> element -->
    <div class="loader-container">
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was trying to do.